# Woo Commerce - troubleshooting a signature error code with ERMS

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, opayo

I'm currently troubleshooting the Retail Merchant Services Plugin for WooCommerce and receiving an invalid Signature error :

```
ERROR: 66343 - ERROR CODE (RC_INVALID_SIGNATURE)
```

Given the lack of support from ERMS and my lack of coding skills beyond Html 5 and CSS. I am looking for an alternative payment plugin that works out of the box ! (the reason I find myself looking at Woo Commerce and their Sagepay Payment Plugin and find myself in Stackoverflow)

Can anyone tell me if there are generic test settings / generic account setup for the WooCommerce Sagepay Plugin to test it without having a Sagepay Account ? or better yet if there was a way to test the plugin before spending $79 to find myself no where nearer solving a payment gateway issue ?

I have an account for ERMS but given the lack of support I wanted to try an alternative.

Any help is appreciated.

If this isn't the appropriate forum to ask my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

That message appears when the Test Merchant ID and Test Merchant Secret are incorrect.

In my case (Opencart rather than Woocommerce), the test account information in the email from RMS was incorrect. The correct Test Merchant ID and Test Merchant Secret were shown in the placeholder text on the Gateway Config screen.